# Edit function not saving changes to state data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, edit

I am trying to provide functionality in my webpage for editing state data.

Here is the state structure

```
state = {
  eventList:[
    {
       name: "Coachella"
       list: [
          {
             id: 1,
             name: "Eminem"
             type: "rap"
          }
          {
             id: 2,
             name: "Kendrick Lamar"
             type: "rap"
          }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to edit the list arrays specifically the id, name, and type properties but my function doesn't seem to edit them? I currently pass data I want to override id name and type with in variable eventData and an id value specifying which row is selected in the table which outputs the state data.

Here is the function code:

```
editPickEvent = (eventData, id) => {
     const eventListNew = this.state.eventList;
     eventListNew.map((event) => {
       event.list.map((single) => {
         if (single.id == id) {
           single = eventData;
         }
       });
     });
     this.setState({
       eventList: eventListNew,
     });
   };
```

When I run the code the function doesn't alter the single map variable and I can't seem to pinpoint the reason why. Any help would be great

edit:

Implementing Captain Mhmdrz_A's solution

```
editPickEvent = (eventData, id) => {
 const eventListNew = this.state.eventList.map((event) => {
   event.list.map((single) => {
     if (single.id == id) {
       single = eventData;
     }
   });
 });
 this.setState({
   eventList: eventListNew,
 });
```

};

I get a new error saying Cannot read property list of undefined in another file that uses the map function to render the state data to the table?

This is the part of the other file causing the error:

```
render() {
const EventsList = this.props.eventList.map((event) => {
  return event.list.map((single) => {
    return (
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out primitive values are pass by value in javascript, which I didn't know and why the assignment wasn't working in some of the previous suggested answers. Here is the code that got it working for me:

```
 editEvent = (EventData, id) => {
     const eventListNew = this.state.eventList.map((event) => {
       const newList = event.list.map((single) => {
         return single.id == id ? EventData : single;
       });
       return { ...event, list: newList };
     });
     this.setState({
       eventList: eventListNew,
     });
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) return a new array every time, but you are not assigning it to anything;

```
editPickEvent = (eventData, id) => {
     const eventListNew = this.state.eventList.map((event) => {
       event.list.forEach((single) => {
         if (single.id == id) {
           single = eventData;
         }
       });
       return event
     });
     this.setState({
       eventList: eventListNew,
     });
   };
```

Comment: when I implement this I get an error "Cannot read property 'list' of undefined in another file that uses a map to display the state data in the table. Seems like it has trouble rendering the updated data to the table? Please see edited post

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A, i think working just with forEach is an easier fix. Also, nothing gets returned from .map. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @RichardDesouza If any obj inside the event array doesn't have the `list` item that  error would throw

Comment: @RobertFedus `.forEach()` will mutate the original array which is just another reference to the state itself, and REACT recommends us not to mutate the state directly, without `setState`

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A when I try to console.log(eventListNew) after the assignment it returns undefined

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A I added the return but it returns the arrays as all undefined. I also added a return to the single = eventData but it just returns eventData and all other arrays undefined :( Is there any way to keep the previous state data and just modify the one selected?

Comment: @RichardDesouza I think I  got what you wanted to do, absolutely there is an easier way, using `filter()`

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A I tried to implement your edit and it compiles but it doesn't edit the state data. I tried console.log(eventListNew) after the assignment but it just returns the original unaltered arrays

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A I also tried putting returns next to event.list.for Each and single=eventData but still the same thing

Comment: @RichardDesouza dude make a  fiddle, this code should work,

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A not sure what else I can do besides add those returns lol

Comment: @RichardDesouza forach doesn't need return, map does

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A Yea I'm not sure I tried saving it to a constant and setting eventList to that but that didn't work. Sorry I'm really new to React so I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A it seems to capture the edit within the if statement because when i console log single it outputs the correct arrays but outside of the forEach function if I console log eventListNew it outputs the original array so I'm thinking it's a problem with scope

Comment: @RichardDesouza remove the if block for debugging purpose

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A I removed one at a time and each and it just assigns each array my eventData but eventListNew still outputs the original unaltered arrays

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A I also tried changing const to var but also didnt help

Comment: @RichardDesouza this is my latest attempt to debug new issues, check the edit section

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A Tried it, still getting the same output

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A console.log(scenario) returns the unaltered array as well D: what is going on

Comment: @RichardDesouza this code will definetly work, the problem is somwhere else in your code, in your logging, the way you use it .. idk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210955/discussion-between-captain-mhmdrz-a-and-richard-desouza).

Comment: @Captain Mhmdrz_A Thanks for the help I got it to work. Please see edited post

Answer (score 2):

```
const editPickEvent = (eventData, id) => {
   const updatedEventList = this.state.eventList.map(event => {
        const updatedList = event.list.map(single => {
            if (single.id === id) {
                return eventData;
            }
            return single;
        });
        return {...event, list: updatedList};
    });
    this.setState({
       eventList: updatedEventList,
    });
}
```

Example Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lake-2q6ez

**Note:** You may need to add more checks in between for handling cases when values could be null or undefined.
Also, it would be good if you can add something similar to the original data source or an example link.

Comment: I'm using javascript for my react file. Seems like that code can only work with typescript

Comment: No, it's pure JS. You can even try it on the browser console.
Or just create a sandbox model for it.

Comment: @RichardDesouza it's js

Comment: @Manish Sundriyal it says types can only be used in a ts file with updatedList underlined in return {...event, list: updatedList);

Comment: @RichardDesouza
Sorry, there was a typo. Fixed it, try now

Comment: Yea I added that = before still getting same message

Comment: I have added in a sandbox link please check  https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lake-2q6ez

Comment: I actually don't have my state in the constructor I have it as state = { } outside of it. Can that make a difference to how things are outputted?

Comment: Yea I it works in there I don't know why i'm getting this ts error though

Comment: I have removed the constructor in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lake-2q6ez
Can you please share your code on a sandbox, similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lake-2q6ez

Comment: @Manish Sundriyal Actually got it to work and it had to do with the fact that primitives were pass by value and so thats why the assignment wasnt working. Please see edited post. Thanks for the help though!